# use non default ssh key with svn+ssh

Tags: svn, ssh

I have a set up script that has parts that require root.  Part of the setup is a `svn+ssh` checkout (which does not need root but is still run as root).  I have a special user for ssh and I set up the keys such that if run as that user no password is needed and the automation works.  However, since its run with sudo as a different user, `svn+ssh` looks in the wrong location for the key.

I know ssh has -i which allows me to specify the key file to use.  Is there a way to sell svn+ssh to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use arbitrary [programs instead of ssh](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html#svn-ch-6-sect-3.4). Simply add the following to your `config` file (`~/.subversion/config`):

```
[tunnels]
ssh-otheruser = ssh -i /home/otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then, you can checkout with

```
svn co svn+ssh-otheruser://...
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -i /home/otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa" svn co svn+ssh://otheruser@your_svn_url
```